# what is the --msg4 option?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I'm using Omnet++ and inet as a library. I get the error, whenever I try to build the Project, 
Type declarations aren't needed with imports, try invoking the message compiler in legacy (4.x) mode using the --msg4 Option
I don't know what that means. Can anyone help? Or tell me at least what that legacy means? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's a compiler option that puts the compiler into legacy mode?

Comment: I would read that as it means you are writing your code using an older method that the library supported in the past and requires this option to use the enable the old method.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with OMNeT++ 5.3 we have made certain backward incompatible changes to the message compiler. That was by default turned off (--msg4 default), but could be enabled with the --msg6 options. INET uses msg6 compatible mode for some time now (since INET 4.0) and it forces it by adding the --msg6 option in the makefiles. If you add code to INET 4, you must also adhere to the new syntax:

See further details about the change in the ChangeLog: https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/src/nedxml/ChangeLog#L298

OMNeT++ 6 will default to the msg6 mode.

Comment: How can I specify this option --msg4?